# How to monitor Spring Batch Threads?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am developing a new Spring Batch application that will be deployed in the K8S as cronjob.
It is a batch processing really heavy, with a lot of IO and HTTP calls. So I decided to use threads for my steps and also use threads to use async processor and writer.

So this whole overview is to ask you if there's a way for us to monitor these threads on Kubernetes. I know it doesn't make sense spring batch expose any metrics, but is there any solution that isn't using SCDF?

Comment: If you're using spring batch 4.2 or above version you have out-of-the-box monitoring capabilities for spring batch. Refer to this [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/monitoring-and-metrics.html) for more information. However, if you require much more information than what this provides, you can customize these metrics and append your own data to it, or have a separate endpoint by fetching data from `JobExplorer` or `JobOperator` interface implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch does not create or manage threads directly, it rather delegates that to a `TaskExecutor` from Spring Framework in different parts of the framework, including concurrent steps and asynchronous processing with `AsyncItemProcessor`/`AsyncItemWriter`.

So if you want to monitor thread usage, all you have to do is to monitor the `TaskExecutor` you pass to Spring Batch. Now how to monitor that `TaskExecutor` is another question. In the Spring portfolio, we use Micrometer for metrics, and you can leverage Micrometer's capabilities to monitor [JVM metrics](https://micrometer.io/docs/ref/jvm) for that.